# Android app display different blocks of text using the same views

Tags: android, layout, view

I am sure there is a better way to do what I am doing in my apps.  The current one I am trying to improve is a list of military cadences.  The way I am doing it now is by loading html files in a web view.

What I would like to be able to do is have one view set up and just be able to add the text portion of what I would be displaying with the html file.

What would be the best method.  I know this is probably a pretty simple thing to do with a sting or array but I am at the very beginner level and would need to be pointed in the right direction to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are searching for [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). You can make a List of what you like tho show to the user and stick that with the an [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) to the ListView.

Comment: I don't think so.  My layout now is a webiew that loads a page with four different links made in html, any selection there loads another html file that has a list of selections similar to what a ListView Displays then when one is selected it displays a block of text.  It just seems backwards that I am using html files when there has to be a better way.    Maybe ListView is correct and I missing something though.

Comment: Don't quite get your problematic. Could you provide some screenshots or something to clarify?

Comment: No Problem.  Here is the [.apk](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B6fX452wEd4jYWZhNTZjYTgtMjA0My00NjFkLThjOTctNDdjYTA1Mjg5NzUz&sort=name&layout=list&num=50) and here are [screen shots](http://imgur.com/a/AR5pQ/screens)   They are in reverse order.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Screenshots made it clear. But I can't help you any further. I only have workarounds in mind, which would not improve your app, sry.

Comment: That's fine.  Thanks for the help.